# How to mock DbContext using EntityFrameworkCore in .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mstest

This question is regarding how to mock DbContext using EntityFrameworkCore in .NET Core application.
Below are my code changes:

My repository class will communicate with sqlserver using DbContext and fetches data.
But while writing unit tests to my repository class i am facing issue related to mocking the DbContext and fetching data from DbSet()

MyDbcontext overrides OnModelCreating() which contains necessary model related constraints as shown below.

MyDbContext class:

```
 public partial class myDbContext : DbContext
 {
    public myDbContext(DbContextOptions<myDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Books>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
                .HasName("BookNameIndex")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.BookDescription)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100);
        });
    }
}
```

StartUp:

```
 services.AddDbContext<myDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Settings.DatabaseConnectionString));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IBookRepository), typeof(BookRepository));
```

My Class

```
public class BookRepository : Repository<Book>, IBookRepository
{
    public BookRepository(myDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public void CreateBook(Book book)
    {
        if (!this.Exists(book.Id))
        {
            this.Insert(book);
        }
    }   
}
```

Repository<> :

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class     
{

    protected myDbContext dataContext;
    private DbSet<TEntity> entities;

    public Repository(myDbContext context)
    {
        this.dataContext = context;
    }

    private DbSet<TEntity> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (entities == null)
            {
               //Exception is throwing here
                entities = dataContext.Set<TEntity>();
            }

            return entities;
        }
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        Entities.Add(entity);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

UnitTest Class and Method:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class BookRepositoryTests
    {
        private readonly myDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IBookRepository _BookRepository;

        public BookRepositoryTests()
        {
            _dbContext = new InMemoryDbContextFactory().GetDbContext();
            _BookRepository = new BookRepository(_dbContext);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            // Arrange
            _dbContext.Book.Add(new Book());
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Act
            _BookRepository.CreateBook(new Book());
        }
    }

    public class InMemoryDbContextFactory
    {
        public myDbContext GetDbContext()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<myDbContext>()
                            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "InMemoryArticleDatabase")
                            // and also tried using SqlLite approach. But same issue reproduced.
                            .Options;
            var dbContext = new myDbContext(options);

            return dbContext;
        }
    }
```

Issue observed in Entities property of Repository<> class:

Exception Message:

> 1. An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnModelCreating in any way that makes use of the model that is being created.
> 2. Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1>)'.

Could someone please help me with this issue ?

Comment: You look like you are using two different entities.  your context references DbSet<Books> Books, but your repository is referencing a Book entity.  Is your declaration in the context incorrect and should be DbSet<Book> Books?  Bigger question why layer a repository on top of ef at all?  ef implements a Unit of work and repository pattern already.

Comment: I have modified the code. Please have a look once again and suggest me how to resolve above issue

Comment: You don't have to mock DbContext. You can configure it to use an in-memory database or SQLite in in-memory mode. Check [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

Comment: You shouldn't use that "generic" repository either. It doesn't help in anything but *does* add a lot of problems. For example, how many and what kind of changes is `SaveChanges` inside `Insert` going to make? The answer is *unknown*. `SaveChanges` persists *all* changes, not just the last one. Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and Unit of Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: If anything, the unneeded repository may be *causing* the bug. `myDbContext` already contains DbSets for all types, and yet the repository is trying to create extra `DbSet`s by calling `.Set<>`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and my issue was that the version of ef core in my test project didn't match the version I was testing against (2.2.6 vs 3.1). Look through the installed versions and make sure they are all on the same version.

I hope this helps you too! cheers!

Comment: I'm using same version.